# GoogleAds search_stream to json

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, google-ads-api

I'm wanting to convert the GoogleAdsRows to json (to then put into a dataframe). when using proto.Message.to_json, i do get json, but it also returns fields that I never queried.

here's the code i'm using (I declare the credentials right before, but left that out so i can post)

```
import proto
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

credentials = {
    "developer_token": developer_token,
    "refresh_token": refresh_token,
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "login_customer_id": login_customer_id}

client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(credentials)

ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService",version='v6')
query = """
        SELECT 
            campaign.id,
            segments.device                     
        FROM campaign 
        WHERE segments.date = '20210405'
        LIMIT 10
"""

response = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id=customer_id, query=query)
for batch in response:
    for row in batch.results:
        newrow = proto.Message.to_json(row,preserving_proto_field_name=True)
        print(newrow)
```

returns (partial shown):

```
    "click_type": 0,
    "conversion_action_category": 0,
    "conversion_attribution_event_type": 0,
    "conversion_lag_bucket": 0,
    "conversion_or_adjustment_lag_bucket": 0,
    "day_of_week": 0,
    "external_conversion_source": 0,
    "hotel_check_in_day_of_week": 0,
    "hotel_date_selection_type": 0,
    "hotel_rate_type": 0,
    "hotel_price_bucket": 0,
    "month_of_year": 0,
    "placeholder_type": 0,
    "product_channel": 0,
    "product_channel_exclusivity": 0,
    "product_condition": 0,
```

so, I never ask for any of the fields above, only campaign.id and segments.device, yet it returns 36 fields... any idea on how to just return the fields I requested? If I print(row) directly, i can see that it only returns the fields requested in the query, so i have no idea where it is grabbing these extra fields from.

thanks!

Edit: I tinkered around with the response a bit more and now I have some decent results, however this seems very complex considering all i want to do is take protobuf -> DataFrame..

```
results = []
for batch in response:
    for row in batch.results:
        pbrow = proto.Message.pb(row)
        newrow = json_format.MessageToJson(pbrow)
        evalrow = eval(newrow)
        df = pd.json_normalize(evalrow)
        results.append(df)
print(results)
```

Output (made-up campaigns/customerids):

```
[                      campaign.resourceName campaign.id segments.device
0  customers/1234567891/campaigns/098765432   098765432         DESKTOP,                       campaign.resourceName campaign.id segments.device
0  customers/1234567891/campaigns/987654321   987654321          MOBILE,                       campaign.resourceName campaign.id segments.device
0  customers/1234567891/campaigns/876543210   876543210          TABLET,                       campaign.resourceName campaign.id segments.device
0  customers/1234567891/campaigns/765432109   765432109         DESKTOP,                       campaign.resourceName campaign.id segments.device
]
```

is there any way to simplify this? what the heck am i missing that this needs 5 transformations to combine the data stream?

Comment: I've not used the Ads service and don't have an Ads account but I'm familiar with Google's APIs and SDKs. Does this simpler [sample](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/master/examples/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py) not work for you? I suspect the protobuf response that you're getting is prepopulated with (defaults, i.e. `0`) for the fields you're not including in your query and these may just be ignored.

Comment: Yeah that example works but I don't want to have to define every single field as it comes out because the fields change for each query. I don't understand why they protobuf message formatter auto fills the fields. Seems odd. And beyond that, it actually changed the device from the text you see above to integer codes for those devices. Just send like it isn't finished and was hoping there was a nice clean way to take that response and throw it into a dataframe. Oh well, it works the way I have it now. Thanks DazWilkin!

Comment: It's difficult for me to answer definitively without being able to access the service but the Ads service's `row` message type is defined once and includes everything. The alternative would require defining the factorial number of possible messages types that could be returned by a query. I suspect the server optimizes by only returning valid values for those fields in your query

Comment: You should be able to programmatically generate results based on the fields you provide in your query. If you `SELECT foo, bar, baz ...` then you should be able to enumerate only those from `row`. Something like `row.foo`, `row.bar`, ....

Comment: to clarify, you are suggesting grabbing the fields selected, then creating some sort of iterative loop that then also builds out the response to create each of those fields in the dataframe? I'm fairly new to the python world, so not sure how that exactly would work. I did try to iterate through the rows like you mention above but ended up getting an error back that the object wasn't iterable - it was something like for item in row: row.item (not exact, but similar to what the "for row in batch.results:" did for rows) and it didn't work. again, could have been doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant but perhaps you can't (the error you mentioned). Sorry, it's difficult to test this when I don't have access to the API. I wonder whether there are test accounts? Perhaps something like: https://gist.github.com/DazWilkin/cb3dc429d2ba410ac500a9b28f3af5ff

Comment: Did you get to a clean result for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this has changed. Not sure if the solution was present at the time of the original comments. Here's the solution though:

```
    for batch in stream:
        for row in batch.results:
            newrow = proto.Message.to_json(
                row, 
                preserving_proto_field_name=True, 
                use_integers_for_enums=False,
                including_default_value_fields=False
            )
            print(newrow)
```

Effectively, I added `use_integers_for_enums=False` and `including_default_value_fields=False`. These are `True` by default.

This would go in place of your following code:

```
for batch in response:
    for row in batch.results:
        newrow = proto.Message.to_json(row,preserving_proto_field_name=True)
        print(newrow)
```

To save you some time, here's a copy of what I'm using:

```
import proto
import json

from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException


def main(client, customer_id):
    ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")

    query = """
        SELECT
          campaign.id,
          campaign.name
        FROM campaign
        ORDER BY campaign.id"""

    # Issues a search request using streaming.
    stream = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id=customer_id, query=query)
    
    data = list()
    for batch in stream:
        for row in batch.results:
            newrow = proto.Message.to_json(
                row, 
                preserving_proto_field_name=True, 
                use_integers_for_enums=False,
                including_default_value_fields=False
            )
            data.append(json.loads(newrow))

    return data
```